# Maven build failing with Connection timed out

Tags: maven, jenkins

So I'm setting up a jenkins instance and have a maven project from git configured.

When I try to build I have an option set to do a "clean package" but im getting the following error in Jenkins logs:  Is there a Jenkins setting Im missing?

[image]

```
    [INFO] Downloading:    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-   plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-20T19:11:04-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/294M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443  [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.32.215] failed: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Is it on windows / Linux? which user runs the build? did you configured settings.xml for that user? is there a proxy that you need to configure?

Comment: This looks wrong: repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.32.215] failed: Connection timed out` ...The location is `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` .Changed something your settings.xml ?

Comment: We had firewall rules on the jenkins server...had to use internal artifactory server to bypass....thanks for the heads up

Comment: hey, for configuring settings.xml - where should location of that file be, on jenkins server ?